# Retrieve User Account information from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I need to retrieve user accounts information from LinkedIn  in my application to do some analysis on users

Information like name, user description , experience, posts  ...etc

Is there an API to extract these information?

Answer (score 0):

[Android Mobile SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk)

[LinkedIn API Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs)

**If you use android mobile sdk following codes will do the job for you**

> User the following urls to fetch LinkedIn data.

```
private static final String HOST = "api.linkedin.com";
private static final String FETCH_BASIC_INFO = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry)";
private static final String FETCH_CONTACT = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(num-connections,email-address,phone-numbers,main-address)";
private static final String FETCH_PROFILE_PIC = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(picture-urls::(original))";
private static final String SHARE_URL = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~/shares";
```

> Don't forget to set permission for accessing above info at both mobile
>   app as well as while registering app in LinkedIn

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.R_CONTACTINFO);
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, this steps return information from authorized user , I need to extract information from others users depends on their names . Is it possible in LinkedIn